# TypeScript - Get ts 7053 error for the created array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, types

I've seen other StackOverflow answers, but none of them seem to be working. Here is the error I am getting:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Paycheck'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Paycheck'.
```

I get this when I try to iterate over the `Array<Paycheck>`, and use their `keys` to get their value. Is there anything wrong with the way I have created my types?

```js
const seperated: Record<string, Array<string>> = {
    date: [],
    taxes: [],
    benefits: [],
    retirement: [],
    takeHome: [],
    total: [],
  };

type Paycheck = {
  date: string;
  taxes: number;
  benefits: number;
  retirement: number;
  takeHome: number;
  total: number;
};

// removing some code to go straight to forEach loop
// p is of type Paycheck
paychecks.forEach(p => {
    // seperated is pretty much the keys of paycheck
    Object.keys(seperated).forEach(key => {
      // p[key] is throwing the error I mentioned before
      seperated[key].push(p[key]);
    });
  });
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I add an index signature appropriately? I've looked at other solutions and can't get it to work.

Comment: *seperated is pretty much the keys of paycheck*.  Can you provide the variable declaration for `seperated `?

Comment: @YongShun I added it to my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to get the key from `Paycheck` via `keyof`.

```js
let k = key as keyof Paycheck;
```

And since all the properties (value) in `seperated` is with `Array<string>` type.

```js
const seperated: Record<string, Array<string>> = {
  date: [],
  taxes: [],
  benefits: [],
  retirement: [],
  takeHome: [],
  total: [],
};
```

Hence, you need to cast the value from each property in `Paycheck` as `string` before the use of `push`.

```js
seperated[k].push(p[k].toString());
```

> Complete code

```js
paychecks.forEach(p => { 
  Object.keys(seperated).forEach(key => {
    let k = key as keyof Paycheck;
    seperated[key].push(p[k].toString());
  });
});
```

[Sample Demo on Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmAHeAnAhleATAXDASvKClgDzQoCWYA5gDQwCCK6AnuVFbQHzcwC8MAN4AoGOJhYM8PAG0AunTESoaAB7wIcxcvEAjeGHgAzSlC0wFSiTBTwolOwFtDUbdZVoA1vAASIF3ddGCgQVQAbIPEAXwBuEREoVmQYAAU0VmAACyIvAWFlKUw8CmoaePFVDQswAFcnAxQKmAMjU3M8OobUZrsHZ1dO+sbm1R9-QJgukeVQiKHuppE4hPD7GEQM7NyLdMyc4C8FfNkhIpkYACIAJgAGa4BGAFoH26fHy4YqzTwHhlaTGYLNcGH1HPAXGA3DAAMxfbx+AIXAAsXzCaEiMFet2i8niIgA9ATbBCQAA3MpwJEwUBYeAhEAwGiMihoSg0LKwUIwYwgFAAUTQ2Rg4RAIEQhOJiBglAgMBAxhCyXpe22hxEm32OwAdLyBUKsgAKaX8PiiGxEuBIVDSLAyuWIPpJGBOWrCqA5GA+VhyhUbLYHLzBADyegAVkQoNrvRBDQhkOhMFgAJS6vmC7KG70CM3BcRrWB5QTZtBy71+1WB5o2eM2pOyb3ybWIWoQI2IBtN0IAZU4ZUNyeT1Zg0SHylH+PEoEgIDW2tFNDj1sT2DH4iAA)

---

Unless you [define the indexable key signature for the Type](https://jibin.tech/indexable-object-in-typescript/), then you can pass the key as `string` for index accessing for the Type:

```js
type Paycheck = {
  date: string;
  taxes: number;
  benefits: number;
  retirement: number;
  takeHome: number;
  total: number;
  [key: string]: string | number; // Here to specify key as string and union Value type
};
```

```js
seperated[key].push(p[key].toString());
```

[Sample Demo (Define Indexable key Signature) on Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmAHeAnAhleATAXDASvKClgDzQoCWYA5gDQwCCK6AnuVFbQHzcwC8MAN4AoGOJhYM8PAG0AunTESoaAB7wIcxcvEAjeGHgAzSlC0wFSiTBTwolOwFtDUbdZVoA1vAASIF3ddGCgQVQAbIPEAXwBuEREoVmQYAAU0VmAACyIvAWFlKUw8CmoaePFVDQswAFcnAxQKmAMjU3M8OobUZrsHZ1dO+sbm1R9-QJgukeVQiKHupuVZH1YSzjL5da4aGAAfKeGekTiE8PsYRAzs3It0zJzgLwV82SEimRgAIgAmAAYfgBGAC0gL+wKBXwYVU0eEBDFaJjMFh+DD6jngLjAbhgAGZod4-AFPgAWaFhNCRGBgv7ReTxEQAekZtkxIAAbmU4MSYKAsPAQiAYDQhRQ0JQaFlYKEYMYQCgAKJobIwcIgECIJksxAwSgQGAgYwhZIC+43J4iK4PW4AOjliuVWQAFDr+HxRDZmXAkKhpFhdfrEH0kjAnLUVVAcjBVvrDZdro8vMEAPJ6ABWRCgNpjToQyHQmCwAEo7fKldknasBO7guI877Cyt4Kx5DbELUIM7EE2WzbQgBlDa0J1FovNGJj5TRSfKUCQEDnG1qmi5n0F7CT8RAA)

Comment: That worked! I don't completely understand why I need to do things this way though. Shouldn't it be assumed that a `key` in an object is always a `string`? Or is that not a correct assumption?

Comment: No, because you didn't define the index signature for the type. I had updated my answer with the solution defining the index signature for type.

Comment: So adding `[key: string]: string | number;` to the type `Paycheck` tells Typescript that my key is a string, and my value for each key is either a string or a number?

Comment: Yes, as your clarification.

Comment: You're the best! Thank you :)